# A simple SDL script that creates a window

Tags: c++, sdl

Is there possibly a way to take out the nested `if` statements without losing the error reports? I am just learning SDL and would like to further simplify my code so that it is readable by me when I look at in a few days.

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    SDL_Window *window = nullptr; //the window
    SDL_Surface *windowSurface = nullptr; //will store current window surface
    SDL_Surface *imageSurface = nullptr; //will store image to be applied to the window

    //inits video
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0)
        std::cout << "Video Init Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl; 
//if error
    else { //creates window
        window = SDL_CreateWindow("Slime Runner Prelim Tests", 
SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
        if (window == NULL)
            std::cout << "Window creation error: " << SDL_GetError() << 
std::endl; //if error
        else { // if all is good with window creation.
            //WINDOW HAS BEEN CREATED

            windowSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);

            imageSurface = SDL_LoadBMP("Images/Background.bmp");
        if (imageSurface == NULL) 
                std::cout << "Image load error: " << SDL_GetError() << 
std::endl;
            else {
                SDL_BlitSurface(imageSurface, NULL, windowSurface, NULL);
                SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
            }
        }//end of window creation if
    }//end of SDL_INIT_VIDEOs
    SDL_Delay(4000);
    SDL_FreeSurface(imageSurface);
    imageSurface = nullptr;
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    window = nullptr;
    SDL_Quit();   


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there possibly a way to take out the nested if statements without losing the error reports?

Use RAII to encapsulate your resources into objects that enforce the create/destroy pairing. You can write your own RAII wrapper objects or (better) use a resource factory that creates `std::unique_ptr`/`std::shared_ptr`'s. [A concrete factory for arbitrary SDL resources](https://eb2.co/blog/2014/04/c-plus-plus-14-and-sdl2-managing-resources/):

```
namespace sdl2 {
template <typename Creator, typename Destroyer, typename... Arguments>
auto make_resource(Creator c, Destroyer d, Arguments &&... args) {
  auto r = c(std::forward<Arguments>(args)...);
  if (!r) {
    throw std::system_error(errno, std::generic_category(), SDL_GetError());
  }
  return std::unique_ptr<std::decay_t<decltype(*r)>, decltype(d)>(r, d);
}
} // namespace sdl2
```

This factory attempts to create the resource, checks to ensure it was created, and returns a `unique_ptr` that destroys the resource correctly when the pointer goes out of scope.  Specific helpers to provide higher levels of abstraction for resources like `SDL_Window`, `SDL_Texture`, `SDL_Renderer`, etc, can be created like so:

```
namespace sdl2 {
using WindowPtr = std::unique_ptr<SDL_Window, decltype(&SDL_DestroyWindow)>;

WindowPtr make_window(const char *title, int x, int y, int w, int h,
                      std::uint32_t flags) {
  return make_resource(SDL_CreateWindow, SDL_DestroyWindow, title, x, y, w, h,
                       flags);
}
} // namespace sdl2
```

You can write your own abstractions over SDL's C API to utilize some of the modern C++ constructs and ideally end with something like this:

```
int main() try {
  auto window = sdl2::make_window("Slime Runner Prelim Tests", 
                                  SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 
                                  640, 480, 
                                  SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
  auto screen = sdl2::get_surface(window);
  auto image = sdl2::load_bitmap("Images/Background.tmp");
  sdl2::blit_surface(image, nullptr, screen, nullptr);
  sdl2::update_surface(window);
  sdl2::delay(4s);
} catch (...) {
  std::cout << "Error: " << error.what() << '\n';
}
```

*Note*: You don't have to use exceptions, but RAII does provide you with the flexibility to choose whichever error handling system you want (exceptions, checked errors, etc) while simplifying the cleanup process.

---

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

If you are not using `argc` and `argv`, omit them.

```
int main()
```

---

```
std::endl
```

Be aware of what `std::endl` actually does.  If you simply want to print a newline character, prefer `'\n'` since it's both shorter and correct.

---

```
SDL_BlitSurface(imageSurface, NULL, windowSurface, NULL);
```

Use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`.